# How to downgrade from ubuntu 19.10 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates, lts, 19.10, downgrade

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 19.10 from 18.04 using 
`do-release-upgrade`.
But now I realize that the new version consumes a lot of system resources and doesn't work properly on my machine.
I want to go back to my previus version.
How can I do that.

Comment: Reinstall. But in regards to that: reinstall 19.10. Or investigate the issue: 19.10 does not consume more resources than 18.04. Maybe you tweak 18.04 to your liking and did not do the same with 19.10

Comment: Why not tell us what problem you're having with 19.10 and we can better help you. Guessing... you probably have a bad GNOME Shell extension.

Comment: Try to create a new user and test 19.10 with this new user for a while. Many problems are user config related.

Comment: I was told and felt when tried 19.10 USB that is much smoother than 18.04. But if you want to go back, take backup of your folders and do a " erase " install. Other methods can lead to more problems.

Comment: @jarvis1234d if you would not find the problematic component in GNOME Shell, then you can always change the desktop environment. For example you can install [MATE DE](https://mate-desktop.org/) with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^` and then select MATE session on login screen.

Comment: The answers in the old post of which I marked this question as a duplicate, remain valid. There is no supported downgrade path. To downgrade, you need to wipe the more recent version and install the old version.

Comment: @N0rbert changing a user's environment to cure a problem is a really bad recommendation. Just because you *probably* run Mate, doesn't mean it's a fix for this OP.